# Parse String API response containing GeoJson FeatureCollection to Angular and add them as pins with pop-up info on leaflet map

Tags: java, angular, typescript, leaflet, geojson

Below is the service method (JsonObjectBuilderService) that converts an object (FeatureCollectionForGeoJson) to a jsonStr. This service method is used in the Get RequestMapping to send a response to the front-end.

The FeatureCollectionForGeoJson object is a class mapped for GeoJson FeatureCollection.

The GeometryForGeoJson is another class that contains the string type with "Point" value and the array that contains the latitude and longitude for the point.

The PropertyForGeoJson  class contains information/properties about that pin that will be displayed in the pop-up when the pin is clicked on on the map.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FeatureForGeoJson {

    private final String type = "Feature";
    private GeometryForGeoJson geometry;
    private PropertyForGeoJson properties;

}
```

```
@Service
public class JsonObjectBuilderService {

    public String transformObjectToGeoJson(FeatureCollectionForGeoJson featureCollectionForGeoJson){
        ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr = null;
        try {
           jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(featureCollectionForGeoJson);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //catch (IOException e) {

        return jsonStr;
    }
}
```

This is the GetMapping that sends the response to Angular

```
  @GetMapping("/power-plants")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAllPowerPlants() {
        try {
            FeatureCollectionForGeoJson powerPlantsToFeatureCollectionForGeoJson ;
            //jpa query for the database to return the information
            List<PowerPlant> powerPlantList = powerPlantJpaService.findAll();
            
            if (powerPlantList.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info("The power plant list is empty.");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            logger.info("The power plant list is populated and has been returned successfully.");

            powerPlantsToFeatureCollectionForGeoJson = transformPowerPlantsToFeaturesCollection.transformPowerPlantToGeoJsonElements(powerPlantList);

            String objectToGeoJson = jsonObjectBuilderService.transformObjectToGeoJson(powerPlantsToFeatureCollectionForGeoJson);
            logger.info(objectToGeoJson);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(objectToGeoJson, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is how the response looks like in the browser

[image]

This is the Angular method that fetches the response.

[image]

This is the Angular component where I call the service method that fetches the response and where I want to add the pins to the map with the pop-ups.

[image]

***How do I take that response from the API (line 27 from Home.component.ts -right above- or the getAll() method from the PowerPlantService) and process it to extract the Point Geometry, to create a pin with it and extract the properties to add to a pop-up to the pin?***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how the back end formats and sends the response, please check in the body of the question.

Below is the service method that performs a GET request to the back end.

```
export class PowerPlantService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(baseUrl);
  }
```

Below is the component method that subscribes to the answer and adds the elements to the map.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private latitude: number = 45.6427;
  private longitude: number = 25.5887;
   
  private map!: L.Map;
  private centroid: L.LatLngExpression = [this.latitude, this.longitude];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
  }
  
  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) { 
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: this.centroid,
      zoom: 2.8
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {
      minZoom: 2.8,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
    
    this.powerPlantService.getAll().subscribe((data: any)=>{
      console.log(data);
      L.geoJSON(data).addTo(this.map) 
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use angular you should use Observables and not Promises, also avoid to post images of code, now I can't copy/paste you code.

what you want to do is return an observable in getAll(), something like this:

```js
// in component
  this.powerPlantService.getAll$().subscribe(
      res => this.featureCollection = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    );
// in service
 getAll$(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(baseUrl).pipe(
      map(data => {
        // transform your data here, or remove this pipe if you don't need it
        return data;
      })
    );
 }
```

you can transform your features in a flat object like this:

```js
return this.http.get(baseUrl).pipe(
      map(features => {
          return features.map(f => {
            const pointGeometry: any = {
                ...f.geometry,
                ...f.properties
            };
            return pointGeometry;
        });
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, will keep in mind for future reference. How do I transform the data because I can't seem to be able to access the inner properties of 'data' ? I used promises because it's a one time transaction, it's doesn't need to be subscribed to it.. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: how do you want to transform it?  also adding a `console.log(data)` before `return data;` might help to vizualize the data

Comment: Please check the final part of my question, in bold. I have also added a picture of how I want to transform the data. The data I need to process is a FeatureCollection containing multiple Features which in turn contain a Point (with lat long) and other information. I want to take every Point and display it as a pin on the map and when I click on the pin have a pop-up display the other information mentioned above.

Comment: it's still hard to know what you want to achieve. How should a Point Geometry look like?
i updated my answer, but honestly you don't have to trasform the data, you can keep the array as it comes from the API.

Comment: The Point Geometry should look like in the picture provided above. It's fine, I have managed to find a solution and now all of the features are properly displayed. Thanks for trying.